# Error running Android Emulator on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 installed with Xamarin for mobile Apps development. I get the following error while running the Android Emulator.

```
    Starting emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 ...
    1>Waiting for runtime checks to complete
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -no-boot-anim -avd pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28
    Emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 cannot be started.
    Runtime checks completed
    Build has been canceled.
```

I made sure I had VTx enabled on my Bios setting. Added the emulator but I'm getting the error above when I run the Xamarin project (A simple HelloWorld project).

Comment: Is Hyper-V Platform enabled?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes...VTx is enabled in my Bios. I guess Hyper-V means VTx

Comment: No in Windows Features make sure to enable Hyper-V Platform

Comment: @Cheesebaron This has been enabled already in windows features. I still have the same error after building the project and running it

Comment: Does it work if you start the emulator first?

Comment: @Cheesebaron It doesn't work bro.

Comment: @Cheesebaron It doesn't work bro.

Comment: What if you recreate the AVD?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I did create it again and there's no change. This is really getting frustrating and discouraging for a first-timer like me

Comment: Sadly, this has nothing to do with Xamarin, but rather the Android SDK and the emulator it provides. If you can try start the emulator from the command line, it should output more information about what is going on: `emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28` You will need to have the Android SDK in your Environment PATH or cd into the path where it is installed. See: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline